# fluent validation in abp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have fluent validation on ItemDto class in Application.Contracts project then in Application.Services I have api method that recieve ItemDto then I call this method from swagger and I want that fluent validation fire before the request go to the server ,like  when I call api method from swagger with required field not sent then swagger return the required vaidation message before reqest send to server like when I use data annotation.
I'm using abp framework

```
public class ItemDtoValidator:AbstractValidator<ItemDto>
{
    public ItemDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.price).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Quantity).NotNull();
    }
}
```

, Then in Application.Contracts module added typeof(AbpFluentValidationModule) and

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
  context.Services.AddScoped<IValidator<ItemDto>, ItemDtoValidator>();
}
```

and in Application.Services in my service added

```
public async Task<ItemResponseDto> AddItemAsync(ItemDto item)
{
  // buisness code to add item
 }
```

Comment: so what is the issue are you facing?

Comment: no validation works before the request send to the server

Comment: show your code for validation?

Comment: Updated question with code

Answer (score 1):

Application service methods that use FluentValidation should be marked virtual. This is because ABP uses an interceptor to validate the DTOs, so the method needs to be overridable.

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Validation

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull()` and so for other properties. It also depends on the default value of datatypes for example `int` is `0`, so you need to check for 0 in that case.

Comment: I'm used RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull() and when I remove Name property from object data and click excute button , then request still send to the api method

Comment: @OmarSeleim why are you not using Required attribute? Any reason?

Comment: this is task for me is to use fluent validation

Comment: @OmarSeleim what value you get for Name property, when you remove from object?